# Question about showing bijection when proving an isomorphism.

Tags: group-theory

Here is the problem

> Prove that the additive group $\mathbb{Z}_6$ is isomorphic to the multiplicative group of nonzero elements in $\mathbb{Z}_7$.

I know the bijection is $f(x) \equiv 3^x \pmod{7}$ Proving it is an injection is easy, but I'm struggling to show how it's surjective given modulo operation. Is just listing out all the elements to show it's bijective considered bad for a proof? The rest of it is easy, as I know I just show that $f(a+b) \equiv f(a)f(b) \pmod{7}$

Comment: yeah, I saw that right after I posted it, thought I caught it in time, oops!

Comment: There's nothing wrong with just listing out the explicit bijection; they're finite groups, so you can write it out in a small amount of space. Either way, I can't think of any easier way to prove it. It's worth noting, however, that since you know $f(1)=3$, you can just show that $3$ spans the multiplicative group. Hence, both groups are the cyclic group of order $6$.

Comment: ok thanks! I think I will do it that way as it gives me more practice than just listing them all

Comment: Here's an easy way: any injective function from a set of finite cardinality (in this case $\mathbb{Z}_6$) to a set of the same finite cardinality (in this case the nonzero elements of $\mathbb{Z}_7$) is surjective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is sufficient to prove that $3$ is of period $6$ which means $3^k\not\equiv 1[7]$ for $1\leq k\leq 5$.

1. Prove that $3^6\equiv 1[7]$

   Compute $3^3$ and $3^2$

the end of the reasoning goes as follows : if a number $a$ is such that $a^6\equiv 1[7]$, its period (the first exponent $k$ after $0$ for which $a^k\equiv 1[7]$) of period (order) a divisor of $6$ i.e. $1,2,3$ ... or $6$.

Comment: thank you very much, i understand perfectly!

Comment: @btcgurl ... and, of course, this is general : you can replace $7$ by any prime $p$ and $6$ by $p-1$  (Fermat's little theorem). Some numbers are of period less than $p-1$ (always a divisor, though). In your case $2$ is of order (period) $3$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $S, T$ are a finite set of same order. Then for a map, $f:S\mapsto T$   $f$ is injective $\Longleftrightarrow f$ is surjective. Now $\mid \Bbb Z_6\mid=6=\phi (7)=\mid \Bbb Z^×_7\mid$